# Could not run asp.net mvc 6 on Docker

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, docker, visual-studio-code

I followed the guidance at [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/ASPnet5) to create an ASP.NET MVC app. I can run it on my local (windows 8). But when I tried to publish it to Docker, and the problem happened.

My dockerfile like

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet:1.0.0-beta4

#install npm in docker image
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

#install bower and grunt
RUN npm install -g bower
RUN npm install -g grunt-bower-cli
RUN npm install -g grunt
RUN npm install -g grunt-cli
RUN npm install -g grunt-bower-task

COPY project.json /app/

WORKDIR /app

RUN ["dnu", "restore"]

COPY . /app

CMD ["cd", "/app/"]
CMD ["npm", "install"]
CMD ["bower", "install"]

EXPOSE 5001

ENTRYPOINT ["dnx", "kestrel"]
```

Then I tried to build it

```
docker build -t thangchung/webdemo .
```

and

```
docker run -i -p 8080:5001 -t thangchung/webdemo
```

the problem when I run above code, it always threw exception

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve project 'kestrel' from /app/kestrel
  at Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.ApplicationHostContext..ctor (IServiceProvider serviceProvider, System.String projectDirectory, System.String packagesDirectory, System.String configuration, System.Runtime.Versioning.FrameworkName targetFramework, ICache cache, ICacheContextAccessor cacheContextAccessor, INamedCacheDependencyProvider namedCacheDependencyProvider, IAssemblyLoadContextFactory loadContextFactory, Boolean skipLockFileValidation) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.DefaultHost.Initialize (Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.DefaultHostOptions options, IServiceProvider hostServices) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.DefaultHost..ctor (Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.DefaultHostOptions options, IServiceProvider hostServices) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Framework.ApplicationHost.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder,
 System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Could anyone let me know why I could not run it on Docker?

Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you use right Docker image from [aspnet-docker github project](https://github.com/aspnet/aspnet-docker) ?

Article about running ASP.NET 5 on Docker at msdn - [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/01/14/running-asp-net-5-applications-in-linux-containers-with-docker.aspx)

**Edit:**

According to article - you're missing

```
RUN ["kpm", "restore"]
```

in `Dockerfile`.

**Article proper to ASP.NET 5 at May 2015:**
https://alexanderzeitler.com/articles/Running-ASP.NET-5-beta4-in-Docker-with-DNX-runtime/

Comment: Yes, I have. I used 1.0.0-beta4 tag, and checked all the version in project.json are the same.

Comment: Check my edit, I think you should use `kpm` (from asp.net) , not `dnu`

Comment: The tutorial from MSDN was old, I think. Now you have to run dnu and dnx command, not kpm and k anymore :(

Comment: I have checked that at https://github.com/aspnet/aspnet-docker/blob/master/1.0.0-beta4/Dockerfile

Comment: This article was updated 3 days ago - https://alexanderzeitler.com/articles/Running-ASP.NET-5-beta4-in-Docker-with-DNX-runtime/

Try: Update `ENTRYPOINT` and add there path to your project

Comment: @ThangChung something worked? I also have plans to check it so please update the topic if you'll get something :)

Answer (score 1):

With the updates from k to dnx you now have to provide a path parameter for the directory containing your project.json.  So what used to be

```
k kestrel
```

becomes

```
dnx . kestrel
```